# How to run my executable file on VNC tight viewer?

Tags: c, linux, embedded-linux, ethernet, vnc-server

I am using an embedded PC which contains VNC server. I am able to access the contents of the embedded PC on my laptop using VNC tight viewer via ethernet cable. I want to run the executable file generated by the Linux operating system on this embedded PC or on VNC tight viewer. Could anyone suggest me some ideas?

Comment: in which system you are running vncviewer linux/windows?

Comment: vnc viewer on windows. I am using virtual machine containing linux OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your pc runnig windows, and you run Linux on virtual machine, and you want to run the binary build from virtual machine on your target board, the one you called embedded PC.  Is my understanding right?

If in that case, you should try to use `nfs`. Run `nfs` server in your virtual machine, mount the shared folder from you embedded PC. So you can immediately see all changed in the shared folder from you embedded PC, as well as run any generated binary file.

A reference here: http://www.rt-embedded.com/blog/archives/how-to-setup-an-nfs-client-on-the-target/

Comment: Embedded PC :I am using an embedded PC containing linux RTOS, which contains VNC server. 

LAPTOP : laptop which I am using contains Windows PC with VNC tight viewer to access the contents of embedded pc. It also contains a virtual machine and linux RTOS is running on that. I am writing my program on eclipse on virtual machine. the executable file generated by virtual machine as to be executed on the embedded PC

Comment: That's exactly what i said. You should setup nfs on your virtual machine. This can avoid copy over after every time you rebuild.

Comment: nfs server on virtual machine. Do I want to use nfs client on the embedded pc ??

Comment: If your client has mount with nfs support. You can try mount cmd on your client side to test.

Comment: thank you very much . Is there any good document ?? could you please suggest me ??

Comment: see this one help or not http://www.rt-embedded.com/blog/archives/how-to-setup-an-nfs-client-on-the-target/

Comment: you sent me the links for setting up nfs client. I have to install nfs server on my virtual machine. Is it right ??

Comment: Yes, server install is easy, just use your package manager to install, yum for redhat, apt-get for debian family

Answer (score 0):

You can use sftp/scp for copiying your binary to your embedded PC and then you can run that binary using vnc viewer,execute below command from your linux machine

```
scp binary username@embeddedPC:/home/username/
```

Comment: vnc viewer on windows. I am using virtual machine containing linux OS

Comment: where should i use the above command (linux or windows) ??

Comment: tight vnc viewer for Windows have support of transfering files to vnc server

Comment: You can run scp command in linux os